# Cannot find arch/arm/kernel/calls.S in raspberry pi kernel

Tags: linux, kernel, system-calls

So I'm having trouble with enrolling my systemcall to raspberry pi.

https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux

You can check above link to ensure that calls.S is missing in raspberry pi kenrel.

So, where can I find it?

Or, how can I enroll my system call without calls.S?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arch/arm/kernel/calls.S` went away in Linux 4.10, specifically with commit [96a8fae0fe09 ("ARM: convert to generated system call tables")](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=96a8fae0fe094b6a26a3ec88b2f097418f269cfe) ([link to that commit in the Raspberry Pi fork](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/commit/96a8fae0fe094b6a26a3ec88b2f097418f269cfe)). Add your syscall to `arch/arm/tools/syscall.tbl` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I finally added my system call to the system.